Unable to use Phi-3 vision in Azure AI Studio
I am following this tutorial.
I created an instance of phi-3-vision-128K-instruct. Once created, I went to the playground to test it.
I am sending the following request. When I click Test, I don't see any response. What I am doing wrong?

JSON (after Matthijs note, but I am still not getting response)
{
  "input_data": {
    "input_string": [
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "how can you help me"
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "temperature": 0.7,
      "top_p": 0.9,
      "max_new_tokens": 1024
    }
  }
}


Please upload the JSON you're sending instead of a screenshot. Also your screenshot doesn't show the complete JSON. You have a typo in your JSON. It's temperature instead of temperator. I just tested with this JSON and it works:
{
  "input_data": {
    "input_string": [
      {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "how can you help me"
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
      "temperature": 0.7,
      "top_p": 0.9,
      "max_new_tokens": 1024
    }
  }
}



Thanks. I tried your json. I don't get error but I don't see any response. Did you get a response? Where do you see it?

The output should appear right below the button. I've updated my answer. If you don't see it, you have an additional issue. Make sure your deployment is in the ✅ Succeeded state.
